# Are if statements considered as an Iteration

Tags: vb.net, iteration

Hello I'm just wondering whether an 'if' statement can be considered as an Iteration. Because Iteration is used until a certain criteria is meet to allow the code to continue.

Comment: An `If` statement is a conditional statement. An iterative statement *iterates* like `For` and `While`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iteration is one cycle (one time through) a loop. `If` blocks are not loops.

`For` blocks or `While` blocks are loops, and executing one cycle of the contents of one of those blocks — what's inside the `For` block or the `While` block — is one iteration of the loop. If the entirety of a `For` block or `While` block is a conditional `If` block, then the `If` block could be one iteration... but not because it's an `If` block, but because it's what's inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

No, an iteration is a repetition of some code. Once doesn't count as a repetition, else all code would be considered an iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The `If` statement by itself cannot be considered `iteration`. You can run a code block containing an if statement *as many times* as you wish, but this doesn't make the if statement an iterator **by itself**. It's **what calls** that code block which *could* stand for iteration.

`If` statement has ***some*** similarities with those other conditional statements :

- Select Case
- Try Catch

Explicit iterators are the followings :

- For/Next - For Each/Next
- Do/Loop
- While/End While

However, you have *some* logic that *could* turn the **usage** of an if statement as the trigger to **resume** or **stop** conditions of a loop, without the usage of direct loop statements like For or While. But that doesn't turn that if statement an iterator *by itself*, because the iteration is the combination of the if statement and a specific logic allowed by the programming language.

1. Recursion :

   ```
   Private Function ResumeIncrement(ByRef Number As Int32) As Boolean
       Number = Number + 1
       If Number < 10 Then
           Return ResumeIncrement(Number)
       Else
           Return False
       End If
   End Function
   ```
2. GoTo statement :

   ```
   Private Sub TestGoTo()
       Dim Number As Int32 = 0
   IncrementMore:
       Number = Number + 1
       If Number < 10 Then
           GoTo IncrementMore
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

And as [stated by Joel Coehoorn above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27070263/2410892), the If block can contain anything, including iterator blocks triggered by For, While or Do. If you remove the contained block, that doesn't change anything in what the if part is supposed to do : **a conditional check** !

You can also do the inverse, and use an If block to control the way an iteration behaves. Like :

```
    If SomeCondition Then
        Exit For
        ' Or Exit While, etc. ie, using the 'Exit' statement
    End If
```

or

```
i = 0
Do
    i = i + 1
    ' ^^ capture i in Debug or Console

    ' Control the value of i...
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        i = i - 2
    Else
        i = i * 3
    End If
Loop While i < 30
' i = 1, 4, 3, 10, 9, 28, 27, [Exit Do with i = 81]
```

In the two examples above, the If statement is either there to break the iteration, or try again, that said, to *"control the iteration"*, but in no means, to stand for iterator by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is also another answer to clear out *one uncertainty*. You asked

> Are if statements considered as an Iteration ?

(You made "if statements" plural) Then you said

> Hello I'm just wondering whether an 'if' statement can be considered
>   as an Iteration. Because ***Iteration is used until*** a certain
>   criteria is meet to allow the code to continue.

(then you made it singular.. ???) That *"...Iteration is used until..."* should self answer your question alone, assuming you're iterating code blocks (which is the way it is understood here)

But what if you're talking about *iterating some **possible values*** until one meets your requirements..?

```
    If MyValue = "" Then
        ' ...
    ElseIf MyValue.StartsWith("A") Then
        ' ...
    ElseIf MyValue.ToUpper = "TEST" Then
    ' ...
    Else
        ' ...
    End If
```

is similar to :

```
    Select Case True
        Case MyValue = "":
            ' ...
        Case MyValue.StartsWith("A")

        ' blah blah blah
    End Select
```

or

```
    If MyValue = "" Then GoTo EmptyString
    If MyValue.StartsWith("A") Then GoTo StartsWithA
    If MyValue.ToUpper() = "TEST" Then GoTo IsTEST Else GoTo DoNothing
EmptyString:
    ' ...
    GoTo DoNothing
StartsWithA:
    ' ...
    GoTo DoNothing
IsTEST:
    ' ...
    GoTo DoNothing
DoNothing:
    ' Resume...
```

Etc.

**That's not an iteration** ! That's a list of evaluation that are processed *in order*. When a condition evaluates to True, the related code is executed. Unlike iteration, this is just a matter of selecting the right path and resume, not walking the very same path several times (loops)

Yes, you're iterating through a **collection** of possible values (condition states) but NO, you're not iterating the `If` statement. You're only checking the result of ***each*** single If test **once**.